Contest Problem from Berkeley math tournament - 2023.
Contest Problem from Berkeley math tournament - 2023 :
Maria and Skyler have a square shaped cookie with a side length of 1 inch.
They split the cookie by choosing two points on distinct sides of the cookie uniformly at random and cutting across the line segment formed by connecting the two points.
If Maria always gets the larger piece, what is the expected amount of extra cookie in Maria's piece compared to Skyler's in square inches.
Does this problem indicate that the choosing of sides and cutting across in the same cookie every time or a different square shaped cookie.

The wording is a bit odd, but I take it to mean:  What is the expected value of the maximum of the two areas?  Note that that expectation is certainly not $\frac 12$.  Knowing it's the max is proof (up to probability $0$) that it is $>\frac 12$.

Correction:  it's asking for the difference, so if $X$ is the max, and $1-X$ the min,  you want  the expectation of $X-(1-X)=2X-1$.  Of course, knowing the expectation of $X$ makes it easy to deduce this as well.

Let the Purple line indicate a "Cut" on the Green Cookie.
(A) Let the Cookie be cut on adjacent sides like this , where I am showing multiple random attempts :

(B) Let the Cookie be cut on opposite sides like this , where I am showing multiple random attempts :

We have 2 Cases for (B) & 4 Cases for (A) , via Basic Combinatorics.
We have to take "Weighted Average" to get total Expectation.
With Double Integration , we will get Area for Case (A) , where the 2 variables are between $0$ & $1$.
Case (B) is Symmetric , hence I assume that it will work out to Maria getting $3/4$
Let us try to derive that actual value.

When bottom Point is $x$ & top Point is $y$ & the Cut is made :
Area to the left is less than $0.5$ when Center is not included
Area to the right is less than $0.5$ when Center is included
The switch-over occurs when the Cut is through the Center.
Both $x$ $y$ vary between $0$ & $1$
We see that the larger Area is $[(1-x)+(1-y)]/2$ for $y$ between $y=0$ & $y=1-x$.
When switch-over occurs , the larger Area is $[x+y]/2$ for $y$ between $y=1-x$ & $y=1$.
Expected Area :
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} [(1-x)+(1-y)] dydx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 [x+y] dydx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} [2-x-y] dydx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_{1-x}^1 [x+y] dydx$$
My assumption that it will be $3/4$ was wrong , Wolfram Online tool says that it is $2/3$.
Case (A) Double Integration for smaller piece :
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (xy/2) dx dy$$
$$\int_0^1 (x^2y/4)_0^1 dy$$
$$\int_0^1 (y/4) dy$$
$$(y^2/8)_0^1$$
$$1/8$$
Hence , larger piece is $7/8$
"Weighted Average" is $7/8 \times 4/6 + 2/3 \times 2/6 = 29/36$
Extra Amount = $29/36-7/36=11/18$

Thanks for attempting to solve, wonder if you agree with mine

Do you see some thing wrong with my answer ? In your answer (A) What are all the multiple $1/2$ & $1/4$ in the Integral ? (B) Why is it $x_1(1-x_2)$ versus $x_1+x_2$ ? (C) Adjacent Sides is $1/2$ & Opposite sides is $1/4$ : It is not adding up to $1$ : What other Case is there ?

The probability of choosing same sides  $=\frac{{4\choose 1} \times {1\choose 1}}{16} = \frac{1}{4}$ that is excluded

If you draw diagram on the both cases and look at the area of the smaller one, one side is $x_1$ and the other side is $x_2$, you will agree the formula for area, and 1/2 is half the times of the expected value is smaller side

We can not exclude Probability : We can exclude Cases. Hence we have 2 Cases opposite sides & 4 Cases adjacent sides. Probability values are $2/6$ & $4/6$ totaling $1$.

It is uniformly chosen on distinct sides, the prob is defined by picking sides from a uniform distribution, I though, may be you are right

When we have adjacent sides : the smaller area is $x_1x_2/2$ , not necessary to multiple by $1/2$ twice more. When we have opposite sides , you will have to work more : It is not $x_1+x_2$ : Alternately , we can use Symmetry to see that it is $3/4$.

Case B may be incorrect. Please justify the statement "Case (B) is symmetric."

I agree with that , @Displayname , I just used blind intuition there , which might go wrong or might go right ! I will try to work it out carefully & update that in around 6 hours. Other than that , is everything else looking somewhat ok ?

Everything else is ok

I have updated the long cumbersome calculations , @Displayname , with no more wrong assumptions based on blind intuition. I want thank you for catching that !

Let $E$ be the expected area of the smaller piece and one endpoint be $x$ along a side, $x \in [0, 1/2].$
The other endpoint with probability $2/3$rd is on an opposite side, in which case the smaller piece is a right triangle with equal probability one leg is $x$ or $1-x,$ and the expectation of the other leg as $1/2.$ Thus, expected area is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} (x + (1-x)) = \frac{1}{8}$ in this cae.
In the other case, a trapezoid with one base $x$ and other in $[0, 1-x]$ or one base $1-x$ and other in $[0, x].$ Expected sum of bases is $(1-x) \cdot \frac{1+x}{2} + x \cdot (1- \frac{x}{2}) = 0.5(-2x^2+2x+1),$ so expected area is $2 \int_0^{0.5} \frac{1}{4} (-2x^2+2x+1) \, dx = 1/3$
Combining both cases, $E = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{7}{36}.$ Expected excess is $1-2E = \frac{11}{18}.$

Two cases:
Case 1: Two points are chosen at adjacent sides and the probability that it can happen is $=\frac{{4\choose 1} \times {2\choose 1}}{12} = \frac{2}{3}$
If chosen that way, let $X_1$ be the area of the smaller piece then
$E(X_1) = \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} x_2(1-x_1)dx_1dx_2$
$ = \frac{1}{12}$
Case 2: Two points are chosen at opposite sides and the probability that it can happen is $\frac{1}{3}$
If chosen that way, let $X_2$ be the area of the smaller piece then
$E(X_2) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-x_1}^{1} \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)dx_1dx_2$
$ = \frac{1}{9}$
Thus the expected value of smaller piece = X $=E(X_1)+E(X_2)$=$= \frac{7}{36}$
Thus the expected value of larger piece $= \frac{29}{36}$
Thus the expected value of extra amount =  $\frac{22}{36} = \frac{11}{18}$

I think the initial steps are incorrect, Satish. The two points are conditioned to not lie on the same line, so you should not divide by $16$, but by the number of ways Maria and Skyler can choose two distinct sides out of $4$, which is $4 \times 3 = 12$). Given this, the probability that the points are on opposite sides is $\frac 13$ ($4$ out of $12$ choices of sides lead to opposite arrangements), and the probability that they are adjacent is $\frac 23$.

Does it make sense now?

We have $\mathbb E[X_2] = \frac 13 \int_0^1\int_0^1 \min(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, 1- \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}) dx_1dx_2$ I think, because (after division by the line connecting the two points) the area of one of the shapes is $\frac{x_1 +x_2}{2}$ and the other is $1-\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$, so their minimum needs to be taken. The smaller area is  parametri\zed by $x_1+x_2 \leq 1$, but that's not equal to the set ${x_1\leq \frac 12 , x_2 \leq \frac 12}$ , it is larger than it (e.g. consider $x_1 = 0.75,x_2 = 0.2$).

Case 2 incorrect. We are integrating over the region $x_1 + x_2 \le 1,$ not the region $0 \le x_1, x_2 \le 1/2.$
